# How to simplify the code with gg list and patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

`p` is a list with 15 ggplot elements, is there a better code to get the result as follows.

```
library(patchwork)

p[[1]] + p[[2]] + p[[3]] + p[[4]] + p[[5]] +
  p[[6]] + p[[7]] + p[[8]] + p[[9]] + p[[10]] +
  p[[11]] + p[[12]] + p[[13]] + p[[14]] + p[[15]] +
  plot_layout(ncol = 5)
```

---

*accumulate* works well for the first step

```
 p %>% accumulate (`+`)
```

but an error rises with the layout code... *non-numeric argument to binary operator*

```
 p %>% accumulate (`+`)  + 
  plot_layout(ncol = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using purrr::accumulate and `+` as a function

Comment: thanks, but there is an error with layout code, how to fix?